# JS file loading garbled in IE and shows Invalid character while it works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, encoding, gzip

I have a web page which has two external JS files being served from AWS bucket. This works fine in non-IE browsers but when I open the webpage in IE(11), it shows be "Invalid character" error as shown below

[image: Console Error in IE]

When I check the script in the IE debugging tool, it shows the script as garbled as shown below

[image: Garbled JS file in IE]

But when I download that file from chrome and host that locally, it works in IE. I suspect it must be encoding and/or gzip issue? But can't seem to figure out exactly.

HTTP Header of the JS file is given below -

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 211091
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 02 Feb 2019 11:25:08 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Feb 2019 20:14:34 GMT
ETag: 12410f7c12c86758ade878921d54ccea
x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000, no-transform, public
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Sat, 01 Feb 2020 20:14:26 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
```

Comment: Could you provide the js file's reference address and your related codes quoting it?This may be helpful for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm currently dealing with an identical IE11 issue.